# Change Keyboard Layout (Direction) in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, winrt-xaml

So after thorough research over MSDN forums, I have decided to put up my question here for the experts around.

My goal is very simple but unusual. Before I post a question, here's the scenario where I want to implement the requirement;

*There is a huge table (large tablet like Microsoft PixelSense or old Surface machine) of nearly 41" which runs my app on Windows 8.1 smoothly*

*This table (tablet) will be placed between two chairs, one for customer while the other one will be for the agent.*

The app opens from the customer's side and customer enters his required details in a usual way like everyone enters some information in a form.

The unsual part is, the agent sitting on the other side is not able to access the keyboard on his side because Windows (OS) opens up the keyboard only in one direction (unlike Microsoft PixelSense).

I have managed to invert the layout of all the app for the agent but unable to change the keyboard's layout (invert to 180 degrees)

My question is, can I change it anyway? Is it possible?

*I don't want to go for custom keyboard as of now.*

Comment: Have you tried changing the display orientation as a whole, through a call to [ChangeDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411.aspx) ([DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565.aspx)'s *dmDisplayOrientation* member)?

Comment: Hmm, you cannot write any software that is close to being able to compete with the dirt cheap hardware solution.  Give the agent his own ten dollar keyboard.  Or hundred dollar display so he has his own view.

Comment: @IInspectable, how can I achieve it using Windows Store apps? I can see that the official document says it is restricted to Desktop apps only. Secondly, if Windows Store apps can access, can you please explain how can I achieve the change? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry. I overlooked the [tag:winrt-xaml] tag, so calling `ChangeDisplaySettings` is not a solution. At least not from within your application. However, can you not write a native application, that performs the operation, and install a communication channel from your Windows Store App? I don't know, if this is technically possible, or a feasible solution given your deployment scenario.